# What is application level and session level events in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and I need to know exactly what are application level and session level events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All application level and session level events occur in Global.asax file

Application_Init

The Application_Init event is fired when an application initializes the first time.

Application_Start

The Application_Start event is fired the first time when an application starts.

Session_Start

The Session_Start event is fired the first time when a user’s session is started. This typically contains for session initialization logic code.

Application_BeginRequest

The Application_BeginRequest event is fired each time a new request comes in.

Application_EndRequest

The Application_EndRequest event is fired when the application terminates.

Application_AuthenticateRequest

The Application_AuthenticateRequest event indicates that a request is ready to be authenticated. If you are using Forms Authentication, this event can be used to check for the user’s roles and rights.

Application_Error

The Application_Error event is fired when an unhandled error occurs within the application.

Session_End

The Session_End Event is fired whenever a single user Session ends or times out.

Application_End

The Application_End event is last event of its kind that is fired when the application ends or times out. It typically contains application cleanup logic.